# how fft (fast Fourier transform) works

Tags: python, fft, simplecv

I am a learner of python and developing a small project related to image analysis, to learn the concept I tried to understand various python codes, but this time I sucked and can any one explain this code ? Especially the FFT part ?

```
class HeartMonitor(object):

    def __init__(self, window_duration, fps = 30, min_bpm = 50, max_bpm = 200):
        """
        Class which detects heart-beats in a sequence of image colour samples.
        @param window_duration The number of seconds of samples to use
        @param fps             The nominal sample rate
        @param min_bpm         Minimum cut-off for possible heartrates
        @param max_bpm         Maximum cut-off for possible heartrates
        """

        self.min_bpm = min_bpm
        self.max_bpm = max_bpm

        # The maximum number of samples to buffer
        self.buf_size = int(window_duration*fps)

        # Buffer of (timestamp, value) tuples
        self.buf = []


    @property
    def fps(self):
        """
        The average framerate/samplerate of the buffer
        """
        return float(len(self.buf)) / (self.buf[-1][0] - self.buf[0][0])


    def get_fft(self):
        """
        Perform an Fast-Fourier-Transform on the buffer and return (magnitude,
        phase) tuples for each of the bins.
        """
        # Get the "ideal" evenly spaced times
        even_times = numpy.linspace(self.buf[0][0], self.buf[-1][0], len(self.buf))

        # Interpolate the data to generate evenly temporally spaced samples
        interpolated = numpy.interp(even_times, *zip(*self.buf))

        # Perform the FFT
        fft = numpy.fft.rfft(interpolated)
        return zip(numpy.abs(fft), numpy.angle(fft))
```

Comment: Is your problem understanding the fft or the python code that does it?

Comment: i know the theocratic concept of FFT but dont know how this python code implemented FFT so problem is CODE not FFT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`numpy.fft.rfft` is a library function that computes an fft from real data

The samples need to be evenly spaced in the time domain.

Since some samples may not be evenly spaced in `buf` they are interpolated using `numpy.interp`

`self.buf[0]` is the first item of `buf`
`self.buf[-1]` is the last item of `buf`
`len(self.buf)` is the number of items in `buf`

So you end up with the same number of samples, but moved along the time axis so they are evenly spaced (stored in the variable `interpolated`).

Now `interpolated` can be passed to `numpy.fft.rfft`